# How to Resolve the AvoidUnsealedConcreteAttributesRule?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Any one please tell me i am facing AvoidUnsealedConcreteAttributesRule?
Descrption :This rule fires if an attribute is defined which is both concrete (i.e. not abstract) and unsealed. This is a performance problem because it means that System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute has to search the attribute type hierarchy for derived types. To fix this either seal the type or make it abstract.

In  the below lines of code only i am getting this error.

```
public class TestAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

How to avoid the above error ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public sealed class TestAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
```

It's common not sealing classes when it's not intended to derive from them, and this is a performance penalty as per MS best performance practices (although I'm not sure how big is this penalty).